Anyway to customize tooltip colors on Microsoft Edge?
Problem
Edge's tooltip is too light for my taste, compared to other Chromium browsers:



Edge
Thorium









So I was wandering if there's a way to "revert" its color back to chromium defaults, or customizing its color if possible. Note that I'm not asking for custom tooltips using CSS & JS - I'm only concerned about the native tooltips showing the content of title attribute.
Attemps
TL;DR: Found no valuable results from Google, or extensions or themes that change the color. Tried to search edge change tooltip color, but the results are either asking for custom tooltips using CSS & JS, or not even related to browsers. So I refined my query to microsoft "edge" change "tooltip" color -css -javascript, which yields a bunch of Windows APIs, but still no related results.
Specification
In case it helps, I'm using Edge 131.0.2903.51 on Windows 11 23H2, 22631.4460.
